# Convert Array to another array format

Tags: php, laravel

I have this array:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => 10
    2 => 5
    3 => 6
  ]
]
```

I want to convert it to this format of array [10,5,6]

Comment: `$new = $original[0]`

Comment: `$newArr = array_values( $arr[0] );`?

Comment: Try array_values(array_values($someArr));

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel helper : `array_flatten` : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-array-flatten

it will convert

```
array:1 [▼
 0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => 10
    2 => 5
    3 => 6
   ]
]
```

to

```
array:3 [▼
    0 => 10
    2 => 5
    3 => 6
   ]
```

if you want to also reset the keys of you array, you can try `array_values()`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has A very useful class to manage arrays with a lot of helpful methods: its called "Collections"

[Link to the Official Laravel Collections Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections)

You can convert the array to a collection with the "collect" method and use the method "pluck" like this:

```
// The original array
$array =  [
    [10, 5, 6]
];
 
$arrayCollected = collect($array);// This will return a collection!
// Now you can flat the collected array
$arrayCollectedAndFormated = $arrayCollected->pluck(0); // this still a collection
// And to finish you can return it to an array again!
$arrayCollectedAndFormated->toArray();
```